# Method isEmpty for binary tree

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary-tree

I've made an implementation of binary tree in python and wanted to see if it works with isEmpty function. When I tested the code and inserted some values I've notised, that python is somehow deleting values from the tree, because if I check if the root equals None I get True. What am I doing wrong? Underneath is my code:

```
class BinTree():

    def __init__(self, item = None):

        self.item = item
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

class Tree():

    def __init__(self):

        self.root = None

    def put(self, indata):

        p = self.root
        tree = BinTree(indata)

        if p == None:
            print("yey")
            p = tree
            return p
        else:
            while True:

                if indata > p.item:
                    #if bigger, go right
                    if p.right == None:
                        #if right slot is empty, make one
                        p.right = p
                        return
                        #return to go back to the base level
                    elif p.right != None:
                        #if right slot is full, go deeper
                        p = p.right
                        #do not return to keep same level and repeat the loop
                elif indata < p.item:
                    #if smaller, go left
                    if p.left == None:
                        #if left slot is empty, make one
                        p.left = p
                        return
                        #return to go back to the base level
                    elif p.left != None:
                        #if left slot is full, go deeper
                        p = p.left
                        #do not return to keep same level and repeat the loop
                else:
                    #if equal
                    return False
                    #return False if the value already exist in the tree

    def isempty(self):

        if self.root == None:
            return True
        else:
            print("yey2")
            return False
```

and then the values i write in the shell:

```
>>> Tree().put(9)
yey
<__main__.BinTree object at 0x105a57eb8>
>>> Tree().isempty()
True
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never set `self.root`; you only *rebound* `p`. `p` is a separate variable, setting it will not set `self.root`.

Without `self.root` set, your tree remains empty.

Note that because `None` is a singleton, in Python you normally use `is` to test for the object. You made several other mistakes in your `put()` method that you want to correct, like creating circular references with `p.right = p` rather than insert the new `tree` node.

I've picked some different variable names to make it clearer what happens; `newnode` instead of `tree` and `current` instead of `p`:

```
def put(self, indata):
    newnode = BinTree(indata)

    if self.root is None:
        self.root = newnode
        return self.root

    current = self.root
    while True:
        if indata > current.item:
            # if bigger, go right
            if current.right is None:
                # if right slot is empty, make one
                current.right = newnode
                return newnode
            else:
                current = current.right
        elif indata < current.item:
            # if smaller, go left
            if current.left is None:
                # if left slot is empty, make one
                current.left = newnode
                return newnode
            else:
                # if left slot is full, go deeper
                current = current.left
        else:
            # if equal
            return False
```

I'd probably return `None` if the node already existed in the tree, rather than `False`; that way you can better test for the condition:

```
newnode = tree.put(datapoint)
if newnode is None:
    # already present in the tree, do something with that info
```

Your `isempty` method is otherwise correct; it could be simplified though, as the `==` and `is` operators already produce `True` or `False`; just return that outcome:

```
def isempty(self):
    return self.root is None
```

With these changes, the `isempty()` method works for me:

```
>>> class BinTree():
...     def __init__(self, item = None):
...         self.item = item
...         self.left = None
...         self.right = None
... 
>>> class Tree():
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.root = None
...     def put(self, indata):
...         newnode = BinTree(indata)
...         if self.root is None:
...             self.root = newnode
...             return self.root
...         current = self.root
...         while True:
...             if indata > current.item:
...                 # if bigger, go right
...                 if current.right is None:
...                     # if right slot is empty, make one
...                     current.right = newnode
...                     return newnode
...                 else:
...                     current = current.right
...             elif indata < current.item:
...                 # if smaller, go left
...                 if current.left is None:
...                     # if left slot is empty, make one
...                     current.left = newnode
...                     return newnode
...                 else:
...                     # if left slot is full, go deeper
...                     current = current.left
...             else:
...                 # if equal
...                 return False
...     def isempty(self):
...         return self.root is None
... 
>>> tree = Tree()
>>> tree.isempty()
True
>>> tree.put(5)
<__main__.BinTree object at 0x10a520cf8>
>>> tree.isempty()
False
```

Comment: I did everything and double checked. The problem remains. Is isEmpty function correct?

Comment: @user2149616: yes, the function is correct but could be simplified. I added a demonstration to show it works.